# How to trap the back button and refresh the page using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web page which updates progressivly therefore I need the windows "back" button to call a function to refresh the data and not go back a page.
I have the first part working I trap the "back" button with

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit();
```

and confirmExit()

```
function confirmExit() {
    switch (page) {
        case 2:
            countries();
            break;
         case 3:
            counties(page3id)
            break;
        case 4:
            cities(page4id)
            break;
    }
}
```

Which all works well but after the page is refreshed the back button default action kicks in and it loads the previous page. I have tried returning true and false. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Did you tried discovering HTML5 History API?

Comment: I did but I could only make it work once, the second time the back button was pressed it ignored my code and went back one page.

Comment: Please to edit your question with the code you added for managing browser history.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add *virtual* sites to the browsers history. this way the back button will not lead to another website.

use `history.pushState()` to add *virtual* sites.

> Suppose http://mozilla.org/foo.html executes the following JavaScript:
>
> ```
> var stateObj = { foo: "bar" }; 
> history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
> ```
>
> This will cause the URL bar to display
>   http://mozilla.org/bar.html, but won't cause the browser to load
>   bar.html or even check that bar.html exists.
>
> Suppose now that the user now navigates to http://google.com, then
>   clicks back. At this point, the URL bar will display
>   http://mozilla.org/bar.html, and the page will get a popstate event
>   whose state object contains a copy of stateObj. The page itself will
>   look like foo.html, although the page might modify its contents during
>   the popstate event.
>
> If we click back again, the URL will change to
>   http://mozilla.org/foo.html, and the document will get another
>   popstate event, this time with a null state object. Here too, going
>   back doesn't change the document's contents from what they were in the
>   previous step, although the document might update its contents
>   manually upon receiving the popstate event.

*from [MDN: Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)*

the user can now press the back button the number of times you added *virtual* sites. to detect the back button press use [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate)

> The popstate event
>
> A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active
>   history entry changes. If the history entry being activated was
>   created by a call to pushState or affected by a call to replaceState,
>   the popstate event's state property contains a copy of the history
>   entry's state object.

*from [MDN: Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)*

Comment: i added window.addEventListener for 'popstate'. Also a history.pushState after every axax call but the back button still works like a back button.

Comment: nasty browsers .... back button working like a back button, who would have thought about it ....

Comment: do you change the url with every pushState? if you do, even without the popstate event, the history of urls should be showed when you press the back button. are you using a modern [browser with history api support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history)?